# Protractor: Returning an array of objects from a table

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have a table with 3 columns 'firstname', 'lastname', 'birthday', like this:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td id="firstname">John</td>
        <td id="lastname">Smith</td>
        <td id="birthday">Jan 1 2014</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="firstname">Bill</td>
        <td id="lastname">Matthews</td>
        <td id="birthday">Jan 2 2014</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

I want to create a JSON from this table, like this:

```
{
    firstname: "John",
    lastname:  "Smith",
    birthday:  "Jan 1 2014"
},
{
    firstname: "Bill",
    lastname:  "Matthews",
    birthday:  "Jan 2 2014"
}
```

I've trying something like this:

```
var tableRows = [];
element.all(by.tagName('tr')).each( function(element) {
    tableRows.push(
                     {
                         firstname: element(by.id('firstname')).getText(),
                         lastname:  element(by.id('lastname')).getText(),
                         birthday:  element(by.id('lastname')).getText()
                     }
                  );
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand can you explain what should be returned?

Comment: then whats the question ?

Comment: This last part, the tests, doesn't work as expected.  It's returning [1, 2], instead of the JSON objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map), quote from the changelog:

> Added a map function to element.all to apply a function to each
>   element and return the result of the transformation.
>
> Resolve promises if there is an object that contains multiple
>   promises. Added index as a second argument to the map function
>   callback.

Key point here is that it would resolve multiple promises:

```
var items = element.all(by.tagName('tr')).map(function (tr) {
    return {
               firstname: tr.element(by.id('firstname')).getText(),
               lastname: tr.element(by.id('lastname')).getText(),
               birthday: tr.element(by.id('birthday')).getText()
           };
});
```